# Indexing values from a file

Tags: database, arrays, perl, hash

I have a text file database that is structured like this (for each line) `ID#VALUE1#VALUE2`, here's how it looks like:

```
1#foo#bar
2#boo#tall
3#34h3s#kdfjf8
4#asdff34#fret45
```

For my purposes it would be useful to have a mask like this:

```
$ID#$val1#$val2
```

so --- for the sake of the example --- a code like this:

```
print "type ID number:";

$ID=<>;

print "value1 is:$val1, and value2 is:$val2";
```

For a standard `input = 1` (`$ID = 1`) my script will return:

```
value1 is:foo, and value2 is:bar
```

How do I load and index the file in such a way? I was thinking about using an Hash table but it doesn't quite work as it returns only val1. Perhaps it can be done with a simple array.. Is there a clever way to do that? How would it look like?

PS. it is also important for me to retrieve only $val1 OR only $val2

Comment: try putting array in hash table. {1:[foo,bar],...}

Comment: just added something in the post... not sure how to do that..

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are all numeric and there are no gaps in the sequence then you should be using an array, not a hash.

And you can get around the problem of storing more than one value in each element by storing a reference to an array of two values.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die "can't open data file: $!";

my @data;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($key, @values) = split /#/;
  $data[$key] = \@values;
}

print "type ID number:";

my $id = <>;

printf "value1 is: %s, and value2 is: %s\n", @{$data[$id]};
```

Comment: tried simply copy and past the code into a new file and tried to apply to a a file like the one in my example. the following is the output: Name "main::DATA" used only once: possible typo at test.pl line 9.
readline() on unopened filehandle DATA at slurp.pl line 9.
type ID number:1
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at slurp.pl line 19, <> line 1.

Comment: line 9 is "while (<DATA>) {" --- thank you very much for this though, it's really appreciated

Comment: @user2374848 Change `DATA` to `$fh` on that line.

Comment: Yeah!! sorry silly me... I will try work out out to retrieve only val1 or only val2 now.. thanks

Comment: @user2374848: Sorry, that was a remnant from my testing. I've fixed it in my answer now. To access the values separately use `$data[$id][0]` and `$data[$id][1]`.